# is 2^n = Ω(2^(n + k)) for some constant k?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

From the definition of Ω notation, this would imply that `2^(n) >= c * 2^(n + k)`.  Taking the lg of both sides and simplifying, I see that `n >= lg(c) * (n + k)`.  If I pick c = 1, n0 = 1, and k to be some negative constant, then I can see this is true.  I am wondering if this is a correct analysis, and that if I pick a positive k, then it is false.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: As I understand, you can't apply direct math formula's in these notations. I visualize n as very large number close to infinity. then n or any constant n+k doesn't make much difference (in terms of infinity). Hence both notations are equal

Comment: 2^(n+k)=2^n*2^k=c*2^n where c=2^k

Comment: ok, so they vary by a factor of `2^k`, but if k is positive, then the statement is false because the LHS will always be smaller than the RHS by a factor of `2^k`, violating the Ω notation rule correct?

Comment: Take a second look at the definition of Big Omega. For sufficiently large `n`, there exists a positive `c`, s.t. `2^n >= c * 2^(n + k) = c * 2^k * 2^n`. Obviously, `c * 2^k <= 1` has to hold, i.e. `c <= 1 / 2^k`. Such `c` does always exist, i.e. the initial statement is true.

Comment: Ok, so if c = 1 / 2^k, then that cancels the 2^k term, resulting in 2^n >= 2^n, which I know is true.

Comment: So from this, I could also argue that 2^n <= 2^n as well, placing 2^n in O(2^(n+k)), which would imply that 2^n = Θ(2^(n+k)) as well right?

Comment: Yes, correct. Although the notation `f(x) = Θ(…)` is a bit abusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of `Ω` requires that there exists `c` such that `2^n ≥ c.2^(n+k)`.

Clearly `c = 2^(-k)` (or a smaller value) satisfies this condition and `2^n = Ω(2^(n+k))` for any `k`.